# How can I align div to right when float is not working

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and I am trying to create a responsive navbar but float Property is Not Working. Here is the HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Page title</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
                <nav class="nav">
                                <div class="logo" id="logo2">
                                                <h1>&nbsp;Nav</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="links float-right">
                                   <a href="#">Home</a>
                                                <a href="#">About</a>
                                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                                                <a href="#">Work</a>
                                </div>
                </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS code

```
* {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
}
a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
}
nav {
             display: flex;
                background: #000000;
                color: white;
                line-height: 76px;
}
nav {
                height: 76px !important;
}
.logo h1{
             line-height: 76px;
}
a {
                display: inline-block;
}
.links{
                float:right !important;
}
```

I have tried all thing I think of like padding, Increasing logo width, etc. But it make it unresponsive on bigger screen

Comment: hi , add  ` justify-content: space-between`  to nav styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: (Using Float)**

Remove `display: flex;` from `nav` CSS and add `float: left;` on `.logo` CSS.

```
nav {
 background: #000000;
 color: white;
 line-height: 76px;
}
.logo {
 float: left;
}
```

**Solution 2: (Using Flex)**

Just add `justify-content: space-between;` in `nav` CSS.

```
nav {
 display: flex;
 background: #000000;
 color: white;
 line-height: 76px;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I hope it'll help you out, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nav style

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 0):

add  `justify-content: space-between` to nav styles

```css
* {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
}
a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
}
nav {
             display: flex;
                background: #000000;
                color: white;
                line-height: 76px;
                justify-content: space-between;
}
nav {
                height: 76px !important;
}
.logo h1{
             line-height: 76px;
}
a {
                display: inline-block;
}
.links{
                float:right !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Page title</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
                <nav class="nav">
                                <div class="logo" id="logo2">
                                                <h1>&nbsp;Nav</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="links float-right">
                                   <a href="#">Home</a>
                                                <a href="#">About</a>
                                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                                                <a href="#">Work</a>
                                </div>
                </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add in nav css ( justify-content: space-between;)

nav {
display: flex;

```
            background: #000000;
            color: white;
            line-height: 76px;

         justify-content: space-between;
```

}

```css
* {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
}
a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
}
nav {
             display: flex;
                background: #000000;
                color: white;
                line-height: 76px;
                 justify-content: space-between;
}
nav {
                height: 76px !important;
}
.logo h1{
             line-height: 76px;
}
a {
                display: inline-block;
}
.links{
                float:right !important;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="nav">
                                <div class="logo" id="logo2">
                                                <h1>&nbsp;Nav</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="links float-right">
                                   <a href="#">Home</a>
                                                <a href="#">About</a>
                                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                                                <a href="#">Work</a>
                                </div>
                </nav>
```